# How can I obtain more detailed error messages from the Nest Firebase API?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nest-api

Currently I'm connecting to the Nest Thermostat API using Node.js. Currently everything in my application works except for obtaining detailed error messages.

Whenever I want to make a change in the structure I do a `_sendUpdate` call on the Firebase (`_fb`) defined as:

```
FireBaseRef.prototype._sendUpdate = function(path, targetValue, callback) {
    log.i('set ' + path + ' (' + targetValue + ')');
    this._fb.child(path).set(targetValue, function(error {
        log.e(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

Which uses the `Firebase.set()` function. Upon error, this callback passes an error object and otherwise `null` as described [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html).

As an example error, we try to set the temperature of the Nest thermostat while it is set to Away. According to the [Nest API guide](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#about), an error message akin to the following should be seen

```
{
  "error": "Cannot change target temperature while structure is Away",
  "type": "https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#structure-in-away-mode",
  "message": "Cannot change target temperature while structure is Away",
  "instance": "31441a94-ed26-11e4-90ec-1681e6b88ec1",
}
```

However, instead I just get a Firebase Warning :

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /devices/thermostats/-GEIJToEG3M9p_jic4J9u7vAgh/target_temperature_c failed: Cannot change target temperature while structure is away
```

and my logging detects a similar detailless error:

```
{
  "code":"CANNOT CHANGE TARGET TEMPERATURE WHILE STRUCTURE IS AWAY"
}
```

**Can anyone explain how I can attain the more detailed error messages?**

*Note: I'm using Firebase API 2.4.2 since v3 presented errors with authentication, so I resorted to the version as used in the example code ([here](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/sample-code))*

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Firebase client library 1.1.3 as specified here.

https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/firebase-client-libraries/